# Create Table and Insert Into using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ddl, create-table

I have a stored procedure that I have scheduled as a job to run nightly at midnight. I want the stored procedure to insert the data into a table when it runs. Do I have to create the table first or is there a way to create the table when the stored procedure runs? My second question is: I then need a job to purge that same table every night at 11pm prior to the stored procedure running again at midnight. Thank you for any help you can provide. I appreciate it.

Here is my Stored Procedure:

I have already created the stored procedure it runs successfully. I have tried using CREATE and INSERT INTO but neither seem to work.

```
USE [TMWSUITE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Wynne_DriverSnapshot] Script Date: 10/22/2019 6:35:18 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[Wynne_DriverSnapshot] as

WITH cte (mpp_id, mpp_firstname, mpp_lastname, mpp_status, mpp_fleet, mpp_terminal) as 
(
  Select mpp_id, mpp_firstname, mpp_lastname, mpp_status, mpp_fleet, mpp_terminal from manpowerprofile where mpp_terminationdt >= GETDATE()),
  cte2 (lgh_number, lgh_startdate, lgh_enddate, lgh_outstatus, rn, lgh_driver1, lgh_class, lgh_class2) as 
(
  Select lgh_number, lgh_startdate, lgh_enddate, lgh_outstatus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by lgh_driver1 order by lgh_number desc) as 
  rn, lgh_driver1, lgh_class1, lgh_class2 From legheader
) 
  Select mpp_id, mpp_firstname, mpp_lastname, mpp_status, mpp_fleet, mpp_terminal, lgh_number, lgh_startdate, lgh_enddate, lgh_outstatus, lgh_driver1, lgh_class, lgh_class2 from cte 
  left join cte2 on mpp_id = lgh_driver1 where rn = '1' and mpp_id NOT IN ('UNKNOWN','TESDR','TESDR2') order by mpp_id
```

I would like to do 3 things with this stored procedure: 1) create a table, 2) run the stored procedure, and 3) insert data into table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a normal select query:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE name = 'smith'
```

To have it make a table you use INTO:

```
SELECT *
INTO person_only_smith
FROM person
WHERE name = 'smith'
```

This can only work if the table doesn't exist. If the table exists, use:

```
INSERT INTO person_only_smith
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE name = 'smith'
```

-

In your case the INTO goes in the final select (not in the CTEs)

```
Select 
mpp_id,
mpp_firstname,
mpp_lastname, 
... more columns ..
INTO your_table_name
FROM ...
```

Now, you say that you want this job to run on a schedule, which kinda implies that the table will have a different name every time it runs. For simplicity you might want to select into a #temp table first, and then use dynamic sql to insert everything into an actual non-temporary table. This means you can have a block of SQL that is large and complex but has the benefit of syntax highlighting for easy debugging, and your dynamic sql is much smaller and simpler:

```
WITH
...your ctes
)
SELECT
...
INTO #mytemptable
FROM ...
```

Because your #mytemptable is created outside of the command that executes the dynamic sql, it is accessible to the dynamic

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000) = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO jobtable_', FORMAT(getutcdate(), 'yyyyMMddHHmm'), ' FROM #mytemptable');
EXEC (@sql)
```

Bear in mind that if you create a temp table inside a dynamic sql it is not available to the code outside of the context of executing the dynamic sql

---

Final note; varying table names are frequently a nuisance, as seen here with the need to drop to dynamic sql to make them work, and even more dynamism in a front end app to retrieve data from them. Consider instead to have a fixed table name and a column that specifies the date of the job. If you select this into a variable first it will have the same value for every row:

```
DECLARE @jobdate DATETIME = getutcdate();

INSERT INTO job_log (jobdate, list,of,other,columns)
SELECT @jobdate, *
FROM person
WHERE name = 'smith'
```

Now, this can be indexed for fast retrieval, and the table name is always the same; all round less of a coding and maintenance headache

Comment: I added the INTO DriverSnapshot in my last Select statement and the stored procedure ran successfully, however, I dont know where it created the DriverSnapshot where it put all the data. How do I find it? Thank you.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'driversnapshot'` return you?

Comment: I actually changed the table name to Driver_Count but the Stored Procedure still runs successfully. When I do the query to search INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for Driver_Count, it returns nothing.

Comment: I found the table. Here is what happened: When I run the stored procedure, it does not create the table even though it runs successfully. If I just highlight the code after the ALTER Procedure line, it creates the table and populates with the data. So now I need to figure out why it doesn't work when the stored procedure is ran but if I run the code within the stored procedure the table works.

Comment: Is the stored procedure being run in a security context that forbids creating tables?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check the security setting?

Comment: Simplest way may be to make a stored procedure that creates a table, no error handling, just a create table statement.. then run it twice